# Store max substring value

Tags: php, laravel-5

```
$exmp = DB::table('cr_tblcomplaintregistration')
            ->select(DB::raw('MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(complaintRegNo,16,length(complaintRegNo))+1 AS int))'))->first();
        dd($exmp);
```

I get:

```
{#337 ▼
  +"MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(complaintRegNo,16,length(complaintRegNo))+1 AS int))": 51
}
```

How do i store the just the value 51 in another variable?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the issue is the varable name?  If so, you can add an SQL alias:

```
->select(
DB::raw('MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(complaintRegNo,16,length(complaintRegNo))+1 AS int)) AS maximum')
)
```

If you want `$exmp` to be the column value, just add that property to the end of your chain:

```
$exmp = DB::table('cr_tblcomplaintregistration')
->select(DB::raw('MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(complaintRegNo,16,length(complaintRegNo))+1 AS int)) as maximum'))
->first()
->maximum;
```

Of course, you may want to get if `first()` is not null before hand.

Comment: when i do dd($exmp), i want the result to be just { 15 } so that i can increment or manipulate the integer value. Is there any other way i can do it?..

Comment: Using this code, you could just use `$exmp->maximum++` to increment, or you could assign `$exmp` in my updated example.